# Custom ROM dev and Networks

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

How are International ROMs made?

---

I have downloaded and installed a little while ago a ROM which is the best I've ever used in terms of speed, smoothness, battery life, and customization and features. However, I am unable to make calls, send SMS and MMS and use the Internet (Mobile Data) due to the fact that I am in Australia and the ROM is not an International ROM.

I am a developer. However my experience in this regard is limited. How would I go about making this ROM support Australian networks? If you know anything at all I would appreciate your help on this. Even if its something as little as a keyword to search for because I have been searching for a long time and have not found a single result that was related.

Comment: Is your phone sim locked??

Comment: @Sameer Sorry for the delay, my phone is not sim-locked. I can use any sim in my phone (Telstra, Vodafone, Optus, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as an international ROM. When you see (for example) a Cyanogenmod ROM "Samsung Galaxy S III International", it means that the ROM is for the international variant of the phone hardware, with the right drivers for that phone's hardware. The international variant might just have a different radio (to work on the right GSM frequency for your country), but sometimes the international variant is a completely different phone, with a different SoC or screen, but in the same case.

If your phone is an "international" variant, then a ROM that's for the US variant will be missing drivers you need. Fixing this problem requires finding the correct drivers for your hardware and integrating them into the ROM.

If there is only one variant of your phone, or the ROM is already for the correct variant, then you don't need an "international ROM". The only important difference between ROMs for different regions (in this case) is that they have network settings for networks in that region. You just need to get the right APN settings from your network operator (you can probably find them on their website), go into the **Mobile networks** settings in your phone, and input the correct settings.

Comment: But he is not even able to make calls. APN is for mobile data rite?

Comment: May be he is in a sim locked phone

Comment: I assumed that it worked fine before he installed the custom ROM, which would rule out the phone being SIM-locked. But I suppose I could be reading too much into the question.

Comment: Sorry about the delay in reply guys I fell asleep.

Comment: @DanHulme, My SIM phone is not locked to any network. I can use Vodafone, Telstra, Optus, etc just fine (well, I could... before I installed this ROM :-)

Comment: @DanHulme thank you for your answer. This is making much more sense now. I do have a question though, I thought that APN settings were only used to enable Internet and MMS to work? I only think this because There are only ever 2 types of APN settings in any phone I've bought, which happen to be MMS and Internet. I've never seen settings for Phone (calls). And when I have (in the past) removed both Internet and MMS APN settings, I was still able to make and receive calls. Is there a way to input Phone call settings for the network for a Samaung phone? (I'm already searching for that)

Comment: @DanHulme If I understand correctly, these drivers basically just tell the phone how to connect, or what settings to use to connect to a network? If that is the case, then if I don't have the drivers, and there is a setting to use to input those settings, that should work, right?

Comment: @Spike I see what you mean now: you're right, the settings for voice calls are entirely on the SIM. If your phone is an "international" variant, then it could have completely different hardware to the US variant. In that case, you need a ROM with the right drivers for that hardware, not just some settings.